# RecyclerVIew OnItemClick return -1

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I want to setup click handlers for views within the RecyclerView row. I want to handle item click from a fragment. I tried to code it by [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-RecyclerView#overview). But when I try to identify which view was clicked, it returns -1.

I have an inteface within my adapter.

```
   public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View itemView, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }
```

Then inside the ViewHolder constructor i call this:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
```

And by last here is the part when i set the listener from my fragment:

```
mFollowingAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FollowingAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
                    Log.d(Constants.TAG, itemView.getId() + " " + position);
            }
        });
```

Full VIewHolder code:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView request_author_profile;
        private TextView request_name;
        private ImageView request_accept;
        private ImageView request_decline;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            request_author_profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            request_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.request_name);
            request_decline = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_request_decline);
            request_accept = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_request_accept);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please post your ViewHolder code.

Comment: what is -1? the id or the position?

Comment: updated ful viewholder code
the -1 is the id, the position is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the anonymous intermediate listener in the `onBindViewHolder()` method instead of the ViewHolder constructor, passing the item's position in the data set to `onItemClick()` instead of `getLayoutPosition()`.

The purpose of a ViewHolder is to represent a single list item visible on the screen, initially unrelated to any underlying piece of data. `onBindBiewHolder()` method binds it to an item in a data set for as long as the item should be displayed. Setting the intermediate listener there will assure that the position of the item in the data set will be passed to the client listener.

Here's a simplified example:

Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    /* this is the public listener that you set from the outside of the adapter */
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        /* update the intermediate listener so that it passes
         * the correct position to the public listener */
        holder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
        /* ... */
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View mView;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        mView = itemView;
    }

    /* delegate the setter to the (root) view */
    public setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        mView.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Note that this is note a very good implementation performance-wise, because it creates a new listener object every time a ViewHolder is bound, but I think it conveys the idea well. A better solution would be to keep a field in the ViewHolder describing a position in the data set, use it in the intermediate listener and update its value in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: Thanks, friend, but i'm a newbie, can U explain how should i add the listener to the viewHolder? There is no standart method. Can I ccreate it in my ViewHolder class, and call it in bindVIewHolder?

Comment: I've added an example implementation to the answer. Hope that helps.